# Abaqus pre.exe error code 529697949

Tags: abaqus

When I try to submit a job, I always get an error. In log I see this message:

> The executable pre.exe aborted with system error code 529697949. Please check the .dat, .msg, and .sta files for error messages if the files exist.

I don't have these files. I looked for the solution, but the only idea is that there is not enough free space on my hard drive. I have 20GB free. Does anyone know if something else can cause this error? Or does anyone know how much free space I need for submitting a job in abaqus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found the answer. The problem was solved after I installed Abaqus to user, whose name doesn't contain any cyrillic symbols. Renaming the user didn't help, so, I had to make a new one with name in latin.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this problem when I tried to import the stress status from another odb file, by defining the predefined field as type "stress".

I have solved this problem, by re-meshing the current model, to exactly the same with then meshing in the odb file that I need to read in.

Comment: Your phrasing puts this answer at risk of being misunderstood as a "Me too", which I am convinced it is not. Please [edit] and rephrase. If you feel that your solution might only help in a specific situation, I recommend to phrase as conditional answer like "If the problem is ... then the solution is to ... ."