# Deploy webpack/npm to windows vm via VSTS fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, azure-devops

I've created a ReactJS app using webpack and building it via npm/node. This my first time working with any of these technologies so forgive me if I use the wrong terminology. I have a Continuous Integration build being done via VSTS. The build works though it is rather large (I'm working on code splitting) 56Mb zip file. The issue is when I go to deploy it. I'm again using VSTS to deploy it to IIS on a Windows VM hosted on Azure. The error I get tells me nothing and I haven't been able to find any info anywhere to help. Here is my error:

> 2018-06-15T05:08:04.6837965Z
>   ============================================================================== 2018-06-15T05:08:04.6838094Z Task         : IIS Web App Deploy
>   2018-06-15T05:08:04.6838179Z Description  : Deploy a Website or Web
>   Application using WebDeploy 2018-06-15T05:08:04.6838275Z Version
>   : 0.0.39 2018-06-15T05:08:04.6838346Z Author       : Microsoft
>   Corporation 2018-06-15T05:08:04.6838452Z Help         : [More
>   Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866789)
>   2018-06-15T05:08:04.6838542Z
>   ============================================================================== 2018-06-15T05:08:32.0782958Z ##[error]Exit code -529697949 returned
>   from process: file name 'C:\VSTSAgent\externals\node\bin\node.exe',
>   arguments
>   '"C:\VSTSAgent_work_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.39\deployiiswebapp.js"'.

Could this error be due to the size? One other thing of note. Microsoft documentation shows using Gulp to build the application and I'm using npm so not sure if that makes a difference. Anyway, by all accounts and per Microsoft I should easily be able to deploy this to my VM and IIS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my webpack.config.js if needed:

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
      app: ["./src/index.jsx"],
      silentRenew: ["./silent_renew/index.js"]
    },
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "."),
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "[name].js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
          {
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              query: {
                  presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-3']
              }
          },
          {
              test: /\.css$/,
              loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
          },
          {
              test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
              loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
      ]
    },
    externals: {
      'Config': JSON.stringify(require('./config.json'))
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body'
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./silent_renew/silent_renew.html",
        filename: "silent_renew.html",
        inject: 'body',
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

Edit (adding detail debug log):

> 

```
2018-06-18T14:51:49.9481397Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step:
> 'Deploy Client' 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9483383Z ##[debug]Evaluating:
> succeeded() 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9483610Z ##[debug]Evaluating
> succeeded: 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9483969Z ##[debug]=> True
> 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9484274Z ##[debug]Result: True
> 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9484678Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Client
> 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9489876Z
> ============================================================================== 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9490039Z Task         : IIS Web App Deploy
> 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9490144Z Description  : Deploy a Website or Web
> Application using WebDeploy 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9490246Z Version     
> : 0.0.39 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9490361Z Author       : Microsoft
> Corporation 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9490493Z Help         : [More
> Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866789)
> 2018-06-18T14:51:49.9490607Z
> ============================================================================== 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6671876Z
> ##[debug]agent.workFolder=C:\VSTSAgent\_work 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6814149Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
> 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6814411Z ##[debug]loading
> ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
> 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6814591Z ##[debug]loading
> ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6814783Z
> ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6814948Z ##[debug]loading
> INPUT_EXCLUDEFILESFROMAPPDATAFLAG 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6815124Z
> ##[debug]loading INPUT_PACKAGE 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6815285Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_REMOVEADDITIONALFILESFLAG 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6815445Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SETPARAMETERSFILE
> 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6816129Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TAKEAPPOFFLINEFLAG
> 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6816253Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WEBSITENAME
> 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6816390Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_XMLTRANSFORMATION
> 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6816512Z ##[debug]loading
> INPUT_XMLVARIABLESUBSTITUTION 2018-06-18T14:51:52.6816628Z
> ##[debug]loaded 11 2018-06-18T14:51:53.7943817Z ##[debug]check path : C:\VSTSAgent\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.39\task.json
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.7972514Z ##[debug]set resource file to:
> C:\VSTSAgent\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.39\task.json
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.7972788Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8089699Z ##[debug]WebSiteName=Client
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8213309Z ##[debug]VirtualApplication=null
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8213582Z
> ##[debug]Package=C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a\Nightly Build and Deploy\drop\Client.zip 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8213822Z
> ##[debug]SetParametersFile=C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8214026Z ##[debug]RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag=true
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8214217Z ##[debug]ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag=true
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8214376Z ##[debug]TakeAppOfflineFlag=true
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8214530Z ##[debug]AdditionalArguments=null
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8214710Z ##[debug]XmlTransformation=false
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8214877Z ##[debug]JSONFiles=null
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8215054Z ##[debug]XmlVariableSubstitution=false
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8215393Z ##[debug]Finding files matching input:
> C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a\Nightly Build and Deploy\drop\Client.zip
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8758329Z
> ##[debug]SetParametersFile=C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8759197Z ##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments:
> C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a = C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8760607Z ##[debug]build.sourcesDirectory=undefined
> 2018-06-18T14:51:53.8761173Z
> ##[debug]system.defaultWorkingDirectory=C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a 2018-06-18T14:51:54.2727713Z ##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments:
> C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a = C:\VSTSAgent\_work\r2\a
> 2018-06-18T14:51:54.4839589Z ##[debug]SetParametersFilepath supplied
> :false 2018-06-18T14:52:26.3782295Z ##[error]Exit code -529697949
> returned from process: file name
> 'C:\VSTSAgent\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments
> '"C:\VSTSAgent\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.39\deployiiswebapp.js"'.
> 2018-06-18T14:52:26.3818440Z
> ##[debug]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessExitCodeException:
> Exit code -529697949 returned from process: file name
> 'C:\VSTSAgent\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments
> '"C:\VSTSAgent\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.39\deployiiswebapp.js"'.
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvoker.<ExecuteAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.NodeHandler.<RunAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.<RunStepAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
> 2018-06-18T14:52:26.3822693Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Client
```

Comment: Can you share the whole detail logs by setting `system.debug` as `true`?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT edited my question with debug log.

Comment: That error code cannot be a coincidence can it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950911/abaqus-pre-exe-error-code-529697949 Search for cyrillic symbols.

Comment: @ippi I think this is coincidental because they are totally different systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue and it appears this was all the result of how my .zip file was created during my VSTS build process. I was zipping the entire application folder instead of just my Webpack output folder. Once I made the change the WebDeploy task succeeded in VSTS.